# Why Does Localhost Get A HTTP 500 Error On Redirect?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I am fiddling around with mysql, PHP, and phpMyAdmin and I am making a short little test login and register system. Only problem is for some reason, the register button takes me to the login page, which it's supposed to, but localhost crashes for some reason. Any help?

Edit: You can test it out too if you would like. My Site: http://localhost/

index.php

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Test Site</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login/logreg.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <label>Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
        <br><br>
        <label>Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
```

logreg.php

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "loggedin";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "H2124130E63C8D14871";
$database = "webserver";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password $database);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Database Connection Failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $phash = sha1(sha1($pass."salt")."salt");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$phash';";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1)
    {
        $cookie_value = $user;
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (180), "/");
        header("Location: personal.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Username Or Password Is Incorrect!";
    }
}
else if (isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $phash = sha1(sha1($pass."salt")."salt");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password) VALUES ('', '$user', '$phash');";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
```

personal.php

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "loggedin";
if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
{
    $cookie_value = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    echo "Welcome To Your Personal Area $cookie_value!";
    echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
}
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
setcookie("loggedin", "val", time() - (120), "/");
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: "Edit: You can test it out too if you would like. My Site: http://localhost/" i dont think you understand what localhost is

Comment: I know I was joking

Comment: the only joke in this code, is your insecure queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a comma here:

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password $database);
```

Comment: When I fixed it and click register, it doesn't get added to my database?